# Issue creating div boxes floating left with the same width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 4 boxes floating to left with width of 25% and `margin:0 10px` on the side to give a spacing however the last div is being pushed down.

I tried applying box-sizing but it didn't do anything.

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/JUYwvapBS4Aa8kFV2zH1?p=preview)

```
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>

.box {
  width: 25%;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The size of the div is 25% - but it's plus margin left/right 10px, so they're not evenly spacing.

Comment: try `width: calc(25% - 20px)` with `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: Total width in your case is 100% + 40px > 100%. That's why last div pushed down.

Comment: Yeah I thought box-sizing will fix the margins as well, will give that a try @Pete

Comment: You don't "apply" box-sizing, you _change_ the box-sizing. And there's really only two values, content-box and border-box. Not margin-box. That's why it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comments:

Try `width: calc(25% - 20px)` with `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
.box {
  width: calc(25% - 20px); /* takes care of margin */
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* takes care of padding */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
```

If you can't get the calc to work, you could just remove the margin and use an inner box (usually what I do to make it compatible with the older browsers):

```css
.box {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
.box .inner {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div class="inner">1</div></div>
<div class="box"><div class="inner">2</div></div>
<div class="box"><div class="inner">3</div></div>
<div class="box"><div class="inner">4</div></div>
```

Comment: weird the calc is reading the px as % its giving me 5% width in total.

Comment: hahaha, very strange what browser are you using - it's a new css thing and is only supported in the newer browsers

Comment: I know right, I've used calc before but never tried % minus px. I'm using chrome at the moment, pretty sure chrome uses calc just this one is strange.

Comment: hmm, that is strange - I'm using chrome 51 on windows 10 and the above snippet seems to work fine, but I have added a non calc anwer

Comment: Even on plnkr its showing 5% in total, so strange I'm on Win10 as well and latest Chrome. https://plnkr.co/edit/JUYwvapBS4Aa8kFV2zH1?p=preview

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I have in my less, basically copied your snippet.

Comment: that plunkr seems very random - sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  If I run it in the snippet or in jsfiddle, it works 100% of the time

Comment: Yes I'm not the only one, so you're experiencing it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Like @toby said you have to decrease the percentage of your width. With the padding you end up with over 100%.The smallest I could get it to work was 18%

```css
.box {
  width: 18%;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to decrease the width of the box as that will make it too small for my need.

Comment: You will need to decrease something. With the padding at 10px and the widths at 25% the numbers dont add up.